# SpanNearQuery does not work

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

For some reason, I am unable to get the SpanNearQuery to work. I've tried debugging for the last 3 hours but in vain. Can someone tell me if I'm doing something stupid? Here's my attempt so far:

```
public static void Test2()
{
    Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\LuceneIndex"));
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
    var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);

    var article = new Document();
    article.Add(new Field("Id", "TEST-111111", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    article.Add(new Field("ArticleText", "How should I gather Active User statistics from the log file? There is somewhat more information available on Google.", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

    writer.AddDocument(article);

    writer.Optimize();
    writer.Close();

    IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
    Searcher indexSearch = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

    SpanNearQuery qq = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] { new SpanTermQuery(new Term("ArticleText", "Active")), new SpanTermQuery(new Term("ArticleText", "User")) }, 3, true);

    Console.WriteLine(qq.ToString());

    TopDocs resultDocs = indexSearch.Search(qq, indexReader.MaxDoc());

    Console.WriteLine("Results Found: " + resultDocs.totalHits); // Gives me zero

    indexSearch.Close();
    directory.Close();

    Console.Read();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the text analysis. StandardAnalyzer lower cases the words in your index but your query contains upper case letters (`Active`, `User`).

You will need to either lower case your query terms or, ideally, apply StandardAnalyzer to them. I believe [QueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html) can help you there ([example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29755/Introducing-Lucene-Net)).

QueryParser doesn't support SpanNearQuery. If a SpanNearQuery is required then I think the best you can do is analyze each term yourself.

**Update - QueryParser (PhraseQuery) vs. SpanNearQuery:** QueryParser does support proximity queries but with not as much flexibility as SpanNearQuery. You would pass the following string as your query to QueryParser: `"active user"~3`. QueryParser will convert it to a PhraseQuery with a slop of 3 (not to mention running the query through StandardAnalyzer). PhraseQuery has these differences:

- PhraseQuery **matches terms in order** -- your query would match "active xx user" but not "user xx active".
- PhraseQuery **does not support wildcards or sub-phrases**. For example the following queries are not valid for QueryParser, but you can achieve their equivalent with SpanNearQuery: `"active use*"~3`, `""active user" statistics"~5`
- There are some **[scoring differences](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/PhraseQuery-issues-differences-with-SpanNearQuery-td556005.html)**. I also recall a slight difference in the distance calculation when the slop is really low but I can't find anything about it on the net.

If you're required to match `active` before `user` as your example infers (you set SpanNearQuery's inOrder to true) then QueryParser/PhraseQuery may work for you. (I've personally never used it so I can't speak to its strengths or weaknesses.)

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. I was actually playing with QueryParser too. Would you mind telling me what would be the performance hit in using the QueryParser (as opposed to say, using SpanNearQuery)? QueryParser just seemed so easy to use that there must be some catch to it which I'm missing. Perhaps it takes time to parse but to construct a SpanNearQuery, I still have to run the same analysis on the input phrase isn't it?

Comment: Glad to help out. Check out my update for more on QueryParser vs. SpanNearQuery.